# Create a table in oracle returning a constraint name conflict

Tags: oracle, constraints

I am trying to create a table in Oracle I am using the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_TARGET(
SLS_REP_SK                 NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
MARKET_PRODUCT_HRCHY_SK    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
FISCAL_PERIOD              VARCHAR2(6)      NOT NULL
                           CONSTRAINT VALID_FISCAL_PERIOD CHECK (LENGTH(FISCAL_PERIOD) = 6 AND REGEXP_LIKE(FISCAL_PERIOD, '^\d*$') AND (SUBSTR(FISCAL_PERIOD, 1, 4) BETWEEN '2010' AND '2050') AND (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(FISCAL_PERIOD, 5, 2)) BETWEEN 1 and 12)),
CURR_SK                    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
SALES_TARGET_AMT           NUMBER(18, 5)    NOT NULL
                           CONSTRAINT POSITIVE_SALES_TARGET CHECK (SALES_TARGET_AMT >= 0),
ETL_BATCH_ID               NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
ETL_CREATED_LOAD_DT        DATE             NOT NULL,
ETL_MODIFIED_LOAD_DT       DATE             NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_SALES_TARGET PRIMARY KEY (SLS_REP_SK, MARKET_PRODUCT_HRCHY_SK, FISCAL_PERIOD)
USING INDEX
TABLESPACE DWH_NRM_INDEX
)
TABLESPACE DWH_NRM_DATA
;
```

It is returning the following error due to a constraint name conflict

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.
```

As other questions have suggested use a query such as:

```
select * from ALL_constraints where constraint_name = 'PK_SALES_TARGET';
```

This is returning no results ( I have tried the above with other constraint names and they are returned no problem).

Can anyone help me find my missing constraint?

Comment: Did you try the other constraints? You don't have just the PK, you also have two check constraints.

Answer (score 1):

YOu spesify 3 constraints

```
CONSTRAINT VALID_FISCAL_PERIOD 
CONSTRAINT POSITIVE_SALES_TARGET 
CONSTRAINT PK_SALES_TARGET
```

Please check are any of them already exists?

Comment: Thank you Michael. As expected I am indeed being an idiot. There are indeed 3 constraint and I only checked the one at the end. Sorry for the time waste.